# Generate single dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a method that takes a list of field names. In the method, I am making an API call out to get a record which will contain a list of dictionaries of fields.

API call example:

```
  "fields": [
    {
      "datetime_value": "1987-02-03T00:00:00",
      "name": "birth_date"
    },
    {
      "text_value": "Dennis",
      "name": "first_name"
    },
    {
      "text_value": "Monsewicz",
      "name": "last_name"
    },
    {
      "text_value": "Male",
      "name": "sex"
    },
    {
      "text_value": "White",
      "name": "socks"
    }
  ]
```

My method makeup looks like `contact(contact_id, contact_fields)` where `contact_fields` looks like `['last_name', 'first_name']`

The final `fields` dictionary I am trying to create would look like (not worried about order):

```
{
    "last_name": "Monsewicz",
    "first_name": "Dennis"
}
```

So, basically generate a single dictionary where the key is the `name` attribute from each dictionary in the list, but only if the `name` is in the list of field names passed into the method.

I've tried this:

```
"fields": {x: y for x, y in contact['fields'] if x in contact_fields}
```

Comment: which is your problem? where's your try?

Comment: @Borja question updated to include what I've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> fields
[{'datetime_value': '1987-02-03T00:00:00', 'name': 'birth_date'},
 {'name': 'first_name', 'text_value': 'Dennis'},
 {'name': 'last_name', 'text_value': 'Monsewicz'},
 {'name': 'sex', 'text_value': 'Male'},
 {'name': 'socks', 'text_value': 'White'}]
>>> output = {}
>>> for field in fields:
...     key = field.pop('name')
...     _unused_key, value = field.popitem()
...     output[key] = value
...     
>>> output
{'birth_date': '1987-02-03T00:00:00',
 'first_name': 'Dennis',
 'last_name': 'Monsewicz',
 'sex': 'Male',
 'socks': 'White'}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is there anyway to write this in a one liner?

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't be pretty.  Avoid the temptation to one-liner when it is not appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

How about this one-liner?

```
output = dict((x['name'], x['text_value']) for x in fields)
```

It basically loops through fields, pulls out name/text_value pairs then constructs a dict from it.

Comment: This would work beautifully, but `text_value` isn't always the key. It could one of `text_value`, `datetime_value`, `boolean_value`, etc

Comment: Then maybe something like: "x.get('text_value') or x.get('datetime_value') or x.get('boolean_value')" instead of "x['text_value']".